# Sonata admin, custom query in filter

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using SonataAdminBundle and I have a question about filters in the class MyEntityAdmin.

I have a first function `protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)` for list all fields to be shown on create/edit forms.

If I have a field type entity, I can do something like this:

```
->add('commercial', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'MyBundle:User',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                  return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                            ->groupBy('u.id')
                            ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC')
                            ->setParameters(array(1 => 'Commercial'));
              },)
            )
```

But I have another function `protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)` for Fields to be shown on filter forms, and I have do to the same thing, a custom query on an entity field type, but if I do the same, I have the error:

```
No attached service to type named `entity`
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Filters configuration is quite different than form configuration in sonata admin bundle.

Look at documentation: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html

When you add new filter through `configuratDataFilters` it receives parameters: field name, filter type, filter configuration, form field type and form field configuration.

So if you want only to override `query_buider` for entity choice type you should try call like this:

```
->add('commercial', null, array(), 'entity', array(
          'class' => 'MyBundle:User',
          'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
               return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                         ->groupBy('u.id')
                         ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC')
                         ->setParameters(array(1 => 'Commercial'));
           }
))
```

Comment: Thanks a thousand times!

Comment: 2023 - broken link(